# Mistake in contour integration (inverse Laplace transform)

Tags: laplace-transform, contour-integration

I want to compute the integral
\begin{equation}
  S(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\epsilon - i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s^{3/2}(1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt{s}})} \; ds
\end{equation}

Consider a contour as shown in the figure below.
[image: contour]

We can use Cauchy's theorem to get
\begin{equation}
  S_1(t') + S_2(t') + S_3(t') + S_4(t') + S_5(t') + S_6(t') = 0
\end{equation}
where $S_1 = S$ is the desired integral, the other terms share the same
integrand but use different sections of the contour (with $C_n$ the contour for $S_n$).

One can check that $S_2(t) = S_6(t) = 0$.
We examine $S_2$ first.
Let $s = Re^{i\phi}, \pi/2<\phi<\pi$ so $\cos\phi<0$ and $\cos(\phi/2)>0$.
First we check a limit that will be useful:

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\frac{\sqrt{R} e^{R e^{i\phi}}}{\exp(-2\pi R^{1/2}e^{i\phi/2})}\right|
  =
  \lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\frac{\sqrt{R} e^{R \cos\phi}}{\exp(-2\pi R^{1/2}\cos(\phi/2))}\right|
  = 0.
\end{equation}
Now we look at a part of the integrand
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{e^{Re^{i\phi}}}{1-\exp(-2\pi R^{1/2}e^{i\phi/2})}
  &=
    \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{e^{i \phi}}{(-1)(-2\pi e^{i\phi/2})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{R}}}\frac{e^{R e^{i\phi}}}{\exp(-2\pi R^{1/2}e^{i\phi/2})} \\
  &=
    \lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{e^{i \phi/2}}{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{R} e^{R e^{i\phi}}}{\exp(-2\pi R^{1/2}e^{i\phi/2})} = 0
\end{align*}
where we use L'Hopital's rule. The integral for $S_2$ has this term multiplied by a
$1/\sqrt{R}$, so it will be zero too.

\begin{equation}
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{e^{Re^{i\phi}} iRe^{i\phi}}{(Re^{i\phi})^{3/2}(1-\exp(-2\pi R^{1/2}e^{i\phi/2}))} \;d\phi = 0.
\end{equation}

For $S_6$, we will have
$s = Re^{i\phi}, \pi<\phi<3\pi/2$ so $\cos\phi<0$ and $\cos(\phi/2)<0$.
Since $\cos(\phi/2) < 0$, the denominator in the integrand approaches $\infty$
as $R\to\infty$. Therefore, $S_6(t) = 0$ too.

Now define
\begin{equation}
 2\pi i\frac{d S_n(t)}{d t}
  = \int_{C_n}\frac{e^{st}}{s^{1/2}(1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt{s}})} \; ds = I_n(t).
\end{equation}
Let us examine the semicircular arc $C_4$ parameterised as
$s = \varepsilon e^{i\phi}$ with $-\pi/2 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$.
\begin{align}
  I_4(t)
  &=
    \int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}\frac{e^{\varepsilon t e^{i\phi}}i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt{\varepsilon} e^{i\phi/2}(1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\varepsilon}e^{i\phi/2}})} \; d\phi \\
  &=
    \int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}\frac{i\sqrt{\varepsilon}e^{\varepsilon t e^{i\phi}+i\phi/2}}{1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\varepsilon}e^{i\phi/2}}} \; d\phi
\end{align}
The integrand goes to zero almost everywhere in the limit
$\varepsilon\to 0$, apart from the point $\phi = 0$.
At $\phi = 0$, we will have $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
\sqrt{\varepsilon}/(1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\varepsilon}}) = 1/2\pi$ which is finite.
So the integral $I_4$ is zero, hence $S_4$ is constant. We ignore this value for now and proceed to look at the lines.

Let $s = e^{i\pi} u^2$ for the upper line $C_3$, so $\sqrt{s} = iu$.
\begin{align*}
  I_3(t) &= \int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{e^{-u^2t}}{i u(1-e^{-2\pi iu})} \;(-2u)\;  du \\
          &= -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u^2t}}{1-e^{-2\pi iu}} \;  du.
\end{align*}
For the lower line $C_5$ let $s = e^{-i\pi} u^2$, so $\sqrt{s} = -iu$.
\begin{align*}
  I_5(t) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u^2t}}{-iu(1-e^{2\pi iu})} \;(-2u)\;  du \\
          &= -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u^2t}}{1-e^{2\pi iu}} \;  du.
\end{align*}
Adding the two integrals gives
\begin{align*}
  I_3(t) + I_5(t)
  &=
    -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2t}\left[ \frac{1}{1-e^{2\pi i u}} + \frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi i u}} \right] \;  du \\
  &= -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2t}\left[ \frac{-1}{e^{2\pi i u}-1} + \frac{e^{2\pi i u}}{e^{2\pi i u}-1} \right] \;  du \\
  &= -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2t} \;  du = -i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} \tag{$t > 0$}
\end{align*}

At this point it is clear that something has gone terribly wrong as integrating this result will give $S(t)=A\sqrt{t}+c$, which is clearly *not* the answer. I don't understand which step(s) are wrong though...

---

**Note:** This solution is very much in the vein of the one given by Ron Gordon under [Complicated Inverse Laplace Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/367305/92124) (including the figure), since I was unable to apply the result proved there directly to this problem.

Comment: $\int_{C_3+C_4+C_5} f(s)ds$ is clearly non-trivial to compute and doesn't have a closed-form.

Comment: That's why I took a derivative, otherwise one encounters difficulty in computing $S_4$ near $\phi ~ 0$.

Comment: You made a mistake there.

Comment: @reuns, do you mean the function is not differentiable? I'm pretty sure I've taken the derivative correctly... w.r.t. closed-form, I don't mind if the answer can be expressed in simpler terms (e.g. Bessel functions/elliptic integrals).

Comment: $\displaystyle I_3(t)+I_5(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}-2i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2t}\left[ \frac{1}{1-e^{2\pi i (u+i\epsilon)}} + \frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi i (u+i\epsilon)}} \right] \;  du \ne   -2i\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2t} \;  du $

Comment: Yeah I had a thought that might be the issue but I don't understand how to get around that because you can't apply the residue theorem due to the branch cut... Suggestions?

Comment: Possibly there is a $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-t n^2}$ term appearing (as the inner term $\to$ in some way to a [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) as $\epsilon \to 0$)

Comment: Did you take in account correctly that $f(s) \mapsto - f(s)$ when turning around the branch point $s = 0$ ? Equivalently you can evaluate $\int_{C_3+C_4+C_5} f(s) ds = \int_{(C_3+C_4+C_5)^{1/2}} f(u^2) 2u du$ directly using the residue theorem (the result is a complicated series)

Comment: I fixed the sign error for the semicircle (although that doesn't affect anything). I don't think we can apply the residue theorem though, can we, since the points at $-n^2$ are not isolated singularities, but lie along a branch cut?

Comment: $f(u^2) 2u$ is meromorphic

Comment: @reuns, I'm unable to solve the final contour integral, as completing the rectangular contour gives another similar but distinct integral and I don't have any clever substitutions to proceed. However, Mathematica tells me the residues sum to an EllipticTheta function. Could you post your solution as an answer? It is okay if you leave the series as is.

Comment: $g(u)=f(u^2)2u=\frac{2 e^{u^2 t}}{u^2 (1-e^{-2 \pi u})}$. It is not obvious but possibly $\lim_{K \to \infty} \int_{-K+\epsilon-i\infty}^{-K+\epsilon+i \infty} g(u)du $ is a constant

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing along the $C_4$ contour.  It looks to me like you made some errors in the limit evaluation.  Also, I find it better to expand the numerator in a Taylor series in $\epsilon$ rather than consider a derivative with respect to $t$, but that may just be a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes, there was a sign error in the limit! However, I don't think it affects the conclusion. I've fixed it now. I'm about to post an answer using reuns's suggestions.

Comment: @RonGordon, you're right, I was too reckless. That does give rise to an additional term; I've noted that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes with the original approach:

- The two integrals for $I_3$ and $I_5$ cannot be combined directly without accounting for the residues, as pointed out by reuns. This gives rise to a summation (see answer).
- The limit for $I_4$ has not been evaluated correctly, as pointed out by Ron Gordon. This gives rise to a constant term in $I_4$ giving a linear term in $S$ (see answer).

One can rectify that in the following manner (again, a major part of this solution was pointed out by reuns in the comments).

Let the concatenation $C_3+C_4+C_5 = \gamma$ for convenience.

$$I_+(t) = \int_\gamma \frac{e^{s t}}{s^{1/2}(1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt{s}})} \;ds = \int_{\sqrt{\gamma}}\frac{2e^{u^2t}}{1-e^{-2\pi u}}\;du$$

where $\sqrt{\gamma}$ is homotopic to a vertical line from $\epsilon+i\infty$ to $\epsilon-i\infty$. To close the contour, consider the integral:

$$I_-(t) = \int_{-\sqrt{\gamma}} \frac{2u^2t}{1-e^{-2\pi u}}\;du$$

The sum of the two integrals can be evaluated using the residue theorem. The poles are on the imaginary axis at $ni$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and all have order 1.

\begin{align}
I_+(t) + I_-(t) &= -2\pi i\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{u\to ni}\frac{2(u-ni)e^{u^2 t}}{1-e^{-2\pi u}} \\
&= -4\pi i\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{u\to 0}\frac{ue^{(u+ni)^2 t}}{1-e^{-2\pi u}} \\
&= -2i\sum_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2 t}
\end{align}

where we took an overall minus sign because our loop is clockwise, whereas the residue is defined for counter-clockwise loops.

Evaluate the difference of the two integrals now:

\begin{align}
I_+(t) - I_-(t)
&= \int_{\sqrt{\gamma}} \frac{2e^{u^2t}}{1-e^{-2\pi u}}\;du - \int_{-\sqrt{\gamma}} \frac{2e^{u^2t}}{1-e^{-2\pi u}}\;du \\
&= \int_{\sqrt{\gamma}} \frac{2e^{u^2t}}{1-e^{-2\pi u}}\;du - \int_{\sqrt{\gamma}} \frac{2e^{u^2t}}{1-e^{2\pi u}}\; (-du) \\
&= \int_{\sqrt{\gamma}} 2e^{u^2t}\left[\frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi u}} + \frac{1}{1-e^{2\pi u}}\right]\;du \\
&= \int_{\sqrt{\gamma}} 2e^{u^2t}\;du \\
&= \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} 2e^{(\epsilon+iy)^2t}\;i dy \\
&= -2i \sqrt{\pi/t}
\end{align}

Combining the two results gives

$$I_+(t) = -i\left[\sum_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2t}+\sqrt{\pi/t}\right]$$

From the first contour integral ($\sum S_i = 0$) and definition of $I_+(t)$, we get that 
\begin{align}
S(t) &= -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int I_+(t)\;dt + C \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[2\sqrt{\pi t}+t-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n^2t}}{n^2}\right]+C.
\end{align}
The only pending task is to figure out the constant $C$; for this we can evaluate the integral for $S(0)$ directly.

\begin{equation}
  2\pi i S(0)
  = \int_{\epsilon - i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty}\frac{1}{s^{3/2}(1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt{s}})} \; ds
  = \int_h\frac{2}{u^2(1-e^{-2\pi u})} \; du
\end{equation}
where $h$ is a hyperbola arm with asymptotes $z$ and $\bar{z}$. Instead of
looking at the hyperbola, we look at line segments parallel to the latus rectum (let $u = x+iy$):
\begin{align*}
  &\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{-x}^{x}\frac{2i}{(x+iy)^2(1-e^{-2\pi (x+iy)})} \;dy \\
  &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{2ix\sec^2\theta}{x^2(1+i\tan\theta)^2(1-e^{-2\pi x(1+i\tan\theta)})} \;d\theta \\
  &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{2i\sec^2\theta}{x(1+i\tan\theta)^2(1-e^{-2\pi x(1+i\tan\theta)})} \;d\theta = 0
\end{align*}
While we haven't been careful with the upper and lower limits,
so the endpoints of the integral are not on the hyperbola,
we can fix them to be $\pm(\pi/4 - \varepsilon(x))$ with $\varepsilon(x)$ defined appropriately and
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \varepsilon(x) = 0$. This will not affect the conclusion.
Hence, we get $S(0) = 0$. This gives the result

$$
S(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[2\sqrt{\pi t}+t+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-n^2t}}{n^2}\right].
$$